# How to get the column value from the particular join table using YII framework?

Tags: php, yii

I am having the query like this

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
'distinct' => true,
'select' => array('assets_id'),
'condition' => 'assets_id in (159)',
'with' => array('tbl_asset_mappings'=>array('select'=>array('catid')), 'tbl_assets_details'=>array('select'=>array('filetype','original_filename'))),
'together' => true
));

$result=TblAssets::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

But I am getting all the column values from firsttable only.I didnt get the column values from second tables.why?

My aim is getting assets_id from tblasset,tbl_asset_mappings.catid,tbl_assets_details.filetype,tbl_assets_details.original_filename

How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying for objects, so you will get the relations as child objects as relations like $post->author->name.

You need instead to do a join not a with. In this situation is more easier to write as Join raw-query.

Maybe would be more easier if you just write your own query rather than constructing throughout Yii

Comment: Yes I wrote it.But when I call it from a webservice that query didnt work.Thats why I wrote this.So do you have any idea to write this.

Comment: Don't use with, do it with join. And post back the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can access related object like `$model->relatedModel->attribute`.

Set a break point after `model->findAll()` and look to `$model->_related property`. You must have a collection of related models there.